# Changing citation style to number-letter in papaja Rmarkdown package

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, citations, papaja

I'm writing a scientific manuscript in RMarkdown using the papaja package, which enables me to report my statistics beautifully. However, the journal now requires me to submit a Word document with number-letter referencing. Is it possible to change the referencing style to a number-letter style in Papaja?

I tried opening the LaTeX output from papaja, but it has the citations set out in the text in APA format (e.g. "Apthorp, Bolbecker, Bartolomeo, O'Donnell, \& Hetrick, 2018"), which is not useful to me.

Here's the code from the top of the manuscript:

```
bibliography      : ["PD_sway-1.bib"]

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : yes
mask              : no
draft             : no

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
```

It would be great if I could get a Word document with number-letter referencing that I could then edit, but a LaTeX file or PDF with the correct citation format would be fine too.

Comment: probably this fits better on [tex.se]?

Answer (score 2):

The references are already typed out in APA style in the LaTeX document because they are handled by `pandoc-citeproc` rather than LaTeX. This has the advantage that the automatic reference formatting also works when you output your document in Word format. To get a Word document all you need to do is change the output line in the YAML front matter:

```
output: papaja::apa6_docx
```

Note that the formatting of Word documents that `pandoc` supports is somewhat limited and you may have to fix some things manually. From the [corresponding section](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/limitations.html#microsoft-word-documents) in the `papaja` manual:

> More over, rendered documents in DOCX format require some manual work before they fully comply with APA guidelines.
>   We, therefore, provide the following checklist of necessary changes:
>
> Always,
>
> 1. add a header line with running head and page number
>
> If necessary,
>
> 2. position author note at the bottom of page 1
> 3. move figures and tables to the end of the manuscript
> 4. add colon to level 3-headings
> 5. in figure captions,
>
>    - add a colon following the figure numbers and italicize
>      (e.g. "*Figure 1*. This is a caption.")
> 6. in tables,
>
>    - add horizontal rules above the first and below the last row
>    - add midrules

Changing the citation style works just as it does in any R Markdown document. The work-in-progress `papaja` manual has [a section](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/writing.html#citation-styles) on this:

> Other styles can be set in the YAML front matter by specifying a CSL, or Citations Style Language, file. You can use either one of the large number of [existing CSL files](https://www.zotero.org/styles), [customize an existing CSL file](http://citationstyles.org/downloads/primer.html), or create a new one entirely.

To change the citation style, download the CSL file and add the following to the YAML front matter:

```
csl: "path/to/mystyle.csl"
```

I'm not sure what style the journal requires but most likely a corresponding CSL file already exists.